# Convert to Arrow Function

Tags: typescript

I'm learning Typescript. I want to convert this to an arrow function:

```
function isRandomNumberEven(): boolean {
 return Math.round(Math.random() * 100) % 2 === 0; }
```

I would convert it this way, but what do you do with the `boolean` return value?

```
const isRandomNumberEven = () => {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * 100) % 2 === 0;
}
```

Comment: I would omit it entirely and let TS infer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TS will infer the return type automatically as boolean. but also if you want then do this way

```
const isRandomNumberEven = ():boolean => {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * 100) % 2 === 0;
}
```

Comment: TS is perfectly capable of inferring the `boolean` part, no need to explicitly define it. Also: `const isRandomNumberEven = () => Math.round(Math.random() * 100) % 2 === 0;`

Comment: thats right, TS can infer, but return type enforce the developer to return the appropriate data type. so it help the developer to ensure. :)

Comment: Frankly, there is ensuring the correct type is returned and then there is being pedantic. What *other* type can be expected from this signature? I don't want to argue this to death, but specifying return types in very simple functions only serves to create 
unnecessary code bloat.

Comment: but my opinion, return type is not mandatory when single line arrow function . but multiline function should have return type. and i think it will make sense. ty :)

Comment: it is not, and complex operation also. by the way it can very on developer perspective. but standard way is to write return type always. it is declarative approach

Comment: Except this is not the standard way by a long shot. Even [the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#return-type-annotations) does not think so. Please, let's not invoke "technically it is not" card, it is a one-liner written *verbosely*. If we are to be pedantic, there are only *arrow function expressions with concise body* and no "single-line" ones. 
You are free to your own preference, of course.